# How do I add 'Webcam' Back Under 'Attached Devices' in the session indicator?

Tags: webcam, indicator

I was wondering if there is a way to add 'Webcam' back under 'Attached Devices' in Session Indicator on Ubuntu 12.04 as I know it from 11.10 (image):

[image]

I ask because it was a simple and intuitive way to quickly boot a webcam, snap a picture, and get back too work.

Comment: You could sign [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/972199) to increase its significance.

Comment: I was as free to add a screenshot of what you meant.

Comment: Thank you Jakob. I hade made this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/992937 but now I can mark it as duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thank you for improving my question. I already have myself signed in the first one, and the second is a duplicate.