# Simple Scan is missing in 12.04

Tags: scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add 'Webcam' Back Under 'Attached Devices' in the session indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135182/how-do-i-add-webcam-back-under-attached-devices-in-the-session-indicator)

I was wondering if there is a way to add 'Simple Scan' back under 'Attached Devices' in Session Indicator on Ubuntu 12.04 as it was in 11.10?

I would appreciate it as it was a quick and easy way to access the Simple Scan application.

Thank you very much!

Derrick

Comment: I've closed this one - its really the same - see the duplicate link and the associated bug report.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

> sudo apt-get install simple-scan

Comment: my bad, I think I misread your question.

Comment: Yes, I do have the application Simple Scan but it is no longer listed under Attached Devices in the upper right-hand corner.  It was just a practical short-cut that I had gotten used to.  Thanks for trying!